# problema ao mover imagens para um diretório no servidor

Tags: php, linux

estou tentando mover uma imagem para determinado diretório do servidor public_html/[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] não sei o que pode estar ocorrendo, pois se trata de um servidor linux e basta um `chmod 775 public_html/uploaded` ressaltando que localmente está funcionando perfeitamente o erro só ocorre quando vou para produção.

Comment: E qual é o erro que ocorre? Faltou mencionar isso.

Comment: a imagem não é movida, somente isso.

Comment: já tentou permissão 777? Não é comum mas para efeitos de testes e desconhecendo sua infra, pode ajudar. E se for na Locaweb sua infra de produção, coloca 777 do contra vc poderá ter problemas para baixar ou apagar arquivos posteriormente

Comment: coloquei sim 777 meu é integrator vou enrtrar em contato com o suporte deles